# Find an asymptotic bound for recurrence $T(n)=T(n-1)+n(n-1)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

> Find an asymptotic bound for recurrence $T(n)=T(n-1)+n(n-1)$.

I tried 2 methods and I'm getting very different results.

**Method 1**:
$$
T(n)=n(n-1)+(n-1)(n-2)+(n-2)(n-3)+...+4\cdot 3+3\cdot 2+2\cdot 1=\\
=\sum_{i=0}^n (n-i)(n-i-1)=\sum_{i=0}^n n^2-n(2i+1)+i^2+i=\ast
$$
The dominant term here is $n^2$ so:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n n^2=\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}\le n^3
$$
Therefore $T(n)=T(n-1)+n(n-1)\le n^3$.

---

**Method 2**:
$$
\frac{T(n)}{n!}=\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}+\frac{T(n-1)}{n!}=\\
=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-3)!}+...+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{2!}+1=\\
=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i!}\le e-1\Rightarrow T(n)\le n!(e-1)
$$

Worlfram Alpha yet gives an [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t(n)%3Dt(n-1)%2Bn(n-1)) which is different from the two above.

Comment: Your method $2$ does not work : for the second line (which I guess you proved by induction), you would have needed $\frac{T(n)}{n!}=\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}+\frac{T(n-1)}{(n-1)!}$... Which is correct if you put inequalities, but it is much weaker and explains why your upper bound is really bad (so keep method 1)

Comment: Both methods fail to observe that $T(0)$ is not necessarily equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram says that the solution for the recurrence relation is $t(n)=c_1+\frac{1}{3}n(n^2-1)$, so method 1 works.
For method 2,

1) Why do you have $-\frac{T(n-1)}{n!}$ after first equality?

2) If your goal is to find the tightest bound, the solution for method 1 is better. Method 2 also works but the resulting bound isn't the tightest one.

Comment: it was a typo, edited. And yes you're right regarding Wolfram I missed it.